# Grouping by multiple coefficients

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Good day! I have an output equation that has a very large amount of coeff. `b(x,y)`, like so:

```
8*b(0,0) + 2*x*b(0,0) + 3*y*b(0,0) + 5*x*y*b(0,0) + 4*b(0,1) + 3*x*b(0,1) + ...
```

I need to group by b, so each `b(x,y)` was seperate. I can `Collect[]` by `b(0,0)`, but what abut the other coeff.? 
I'm trying to get something like this:

```
(8 + 2*x + 3*y + 5*x*y) * b(0,0) + (4 + 3*x + ...
```

Any ideas about how to do this?

To clarify: each `x,y` in `b(x,y)` is written as a Subscript. Not all `b(x,y)` have a "full" group.The grouping i'm trying to achieve will correspond to a cell in a matrix. The equation is a matrix row, and there are several equations which will form an equation group. I'm new to Wolfram, so any general advice is very welcome.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: In the future would you please give your input as valid *Mathematica* code?

Comment: Take a look at `CoefficientList[ ]`

Comment: What is your purpose in group the terms together?  For instance, if you're trying to construct the matrix, there are probably other ways to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
expr = 8*Subscript[b, 0, 0] + 2*x*Subscript[b, 0, 0] - 3*y*Subscript[b, 0, 0] + 
   5*x*y*Subscript[b, 0, 0] - 4*Subscript[b, 0, 1] + 3*x*Subscript[b, 0, 1];

Collect[expr, _Subscript]
```

> ```
> (8 + 2 x - 3 y + 5 x y) Subscript[b, 0, 0] + (-4 + 3 x) Subscript[b, 0, 1]
> ```

( `_Subscript` is the [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) pattern that matches any expression with head `Subscript`. )